# Three Leanback Lists not getting focus as expected while navigating between them using Dpad buttons

Tags: android, list, android-tv, leanback

Imagen a Tv with a navigation list to the left side (vertical) as tabs, in one of these tabs there is two lists (list 1 for categories) and (list 2 for channels in each category), here is a representation of the lists |tabs| |category| |channels| |screen continues|
The problem appears when clicking for example left pad in Dpad and while the focus in on the channels list it goes to tabs list, but it is expected to go to categories list, and sometimes if tabs list is focused on and right button in Dpad is clicked it goes to channels list, but it is expected to go to category list.

Right now, the events are handled by checking for focus, and handling each click based on the key Code. but I am looking for better ways of doing that.
Also I am using VerticalGridView for the lists in Xml.

here is a representation of the lists
[image]